# json and multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_model] => HFJ5G1.5
            [product_type] => plat
            [product_return] => graviteits

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [product_model] => HHJ5S2.5
            [product_type] => holle plunjer
            [product_return] => veer       

        )
    );  //Only 2 are shown here i have around 110 values
```

And i encoded this to json by

```
json_encode($array);
```

The resulted jsonString is something like this

```
{"1":{"product_id":"1","product_model":"HFJ5G1.5","product_type":"plat","product_return":"graviteits"},"2":{"product_id":"2","product_model":"HHJ5S2.5","product_type":"holle plunjer","product_return":"veer"}}
```

when i do  alert(jsonString.length); the result is 4 But i want the result to be 2 am i doing something wrong .

Comment: `the result is 4` are you sure that it is related to your json? objects do not support length property. compare `alert({}.length);` and `alert([].length);`

Comment: I think a [ is  missing in my json but i dont know how to add this..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

an object literal has no `.length`

you can count properties using [this method](http://jsfiddle.net/cVs5B/):

```
var count = 0;

for (i in jsonString) {
    if (jsonString.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        count++;
    }
}

alert(count); //count shall have length for you
```

**OR**

since your array didn't have numeric indices (starting from 0), it assumed you used an *associative array*, hence they dumped an *object of items* rather than an *array of items*.

to turn them to numeric indices, all you have to do is use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) before encoding them to json:

```
json_encode(array_values($array));
```

then the json will be an array.. [then you can use length](http://jsfiddle.net/bAn9J/)

from this:

```
Array(
[1] => Array(
        [product_id] => 1
        [product_model] => HFJ5G1.5
        [product_type] => plat
        [product_return] => graviteits
    )
[2] => Array(
        [product_id] => 2
        [product_model] => HHJ5S2.5
        [product_type] => holle plunjer
        [product_return] => veer       
    )
);
```

it becomes this using array_values(), note the indexes per item:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
        [product_id] => 1
        [product_model] => HFJ5G1.5
        [product_type] => plat
        [product_return] => graviteits
    )
[1] => Array(
        [product_id] => 2
        [product_model] => HHJ5S2.5
        [product_type] => holle plunjer
        [product_return] => veer       
    )
);
```

then encoded to json and stored to jsonString:

```
jsonString = [
    {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_model": "HFJ5G1.5",
        "product_type": "plat",
        "product_return": "graviteits"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_model": "HHJ5S2.5",
        "product_type": "holle plunjer",
        "product_return": "veer"
    }
];

alert(jsonString.length);
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my json array am i missing a [ bracket ?

Comment: read my update, it covers it in the second method of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Objects do not support length property: `alert({}.length);` gives `undefined` and `alert([].length);` gives `0`. To find the 'length' of the top level you could do it like:

```
var arr ={"1":{"product_id":"1","product_model":"HFJ5G1.5",
                 "product_type":"plat","product_return":"graviteits"},
          "2":{"product_id":"2","product_model":"HHJ5S2.5",
                "product_type":"holle plunjer","product_return":"veer"}};
var len = 0;
for(var i in arr) len++;
alert(len);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uszaV/

Comment: Is there something wrong with my json array am i missing a [ bracket ?

Comment: @ubercooluk  there is nothing wrong, when you are saving the associative array into the json format it becomes an object in order to preserve the keys. Compare `echo json_encode(array(1,2));` and `echo json_encode(array('a'=>1,'b'=>2));`