# How to efficiently load filtered AJAX content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on an AJAX loaded shopping app, with a [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) layout.

I using a loop to load and display the products:

```
function get_next_entry() {
    $data = next_entries(); //get the ids of the next 6 products
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: $url,
          data: $data,
          cache: true,
          success: function(data) {
                var xml = $(data);
                xml.find('entry').each(function(){
                    var el = $($(this).text());
                    el.imagesLoaded(function() {
                        $collection.append( el ).masonry( 'appended', el, true );
                        el = set_visibility( el );
                    });
                });
                if ($resync) {
                    $collection.masonry();
                }
                get_next_entry();
            },
          dataType: 'xml',
          async:true
    });
}
```

`$data` contains an array of product ids. The HTML of each product is cached by its `id` so they can be retrieved without MySQL queries to reduce the load on my database server, and can be served faster.

I have a jQuery filtering system on the products that toggles visibility.

When a filter is selected I need to only load the products from that filter. When the filter is then deselected I need to resume loading of the whole catalog.

I don't want to do this with multiple MySQL queries as there will be a lot of these queries per user (my loop loads 6 products at a time so a query each loop cycle would be too many).

My current solution is to AJAX get the entire catalog list as an XML list of `id`s with the filters as attributes (so I can filter with jQuery easily rather than JSON) then remove products from this list as I load them:

```
<data>
    <product category="category">id</product>
    <product category="category">id</product>
    <product category="category">id</product>
    ...
</data>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: hello,Is this current approach taking too much time ?

Comment: hi, Not really, the XML list is cached too, so is quite responsive, a little pause in loading as the list is retrieved but not too bad, I'm just interested in people thoughts who might have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hear alternatives, you could use multidimensional Arrays using JSON, like in these two questions:
1) [Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)
2) [json and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306309/json-and-multidimensional-array)

This might reduce some time, since the encoding is shorter than the XML text.

However, I still would prefer your approach, since it's way easier to manipulate and manage the data.